# NetSuite - excluding weekends from date calculation

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

My scheduled script sets a field to store an accrued late fee charge for each day an invoice is overdue. I am comparing the current system time against due date to work out the number of days overdue. However, I didn't take into consideration to exclude the weekend. How can I use my existing code to do this?

```js
var current_date = nlapiStringToDate(nlapiDateToString(new Date()));
var dd = invoice.getFieldValue('duedate');
var due_date = nlapiStringToDate(dd);

if (due_date < current_date) {
  //Other Calculations
  var days_overdue = DateOverdue(current_date, due_date);
}

function DateOverdue(current_date, due_date) {
  var time_difference = Math.abs(due_date.getTime() - current_date.getTime());
  var no_days_overdue_by = Math.ceil(time_difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  return no_days_overdue_by;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works. Note the extra dates are to clear issues from comparing time stamps without hours, minutes and seconds. Not strictly needed for the current_date given how you are generating it but it makes a more general function.

NOTE: I don't believe you should be able to compare dates with d1 < d2.

```
function daysOverdue(currentDate, dueDate){
    var days = 0;
    var due = new Date(dueDate.getFullYear(), dueDate.getMonth(), dueDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
    var fromTS = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0).getTime();
    if(due.getTime() >= fromTS) return 0; // not overdue
    while(due.getTime() < fromTS){
        if(due.getDay() !== 0 && due.getDay() != 6) days++;
        due.setDate(due.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return days;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I will try it out today!

Comment: You're welcome. Also as long as you are working with any ES5 or later Javascript engine the expression d1 < d2 is valid and works. It's the equivalent to d1.valueOf() < d2.valueOf(). This means it's fine for server side Netsuite code and most browsers. (still a depressing number of IE8 instances being used with Netsuite)